# If we change object's reference in Python, why does it sometimes change the id (memory location) of object?

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, linked-list, nodes

I was trying to implement a node for linked list and faced the following issue: When I assign a new object to `m2`and then assign the new variable `c` to the old object associated with `m2` it gives back the same id.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,dataval=None):
        self.val = dataval ##Int
        self.nextval = None ##Node
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self,headval=None):
        self.headval = headval ##Node

m2 = Node(4)
print(id(m2)) # Returns 2309784010704
m2 = Node(5)
c = Node(4) # Assigning same object as previously with m2
print(id(c)) # Returns 2309784010704 which is same as id of m2
```

But if I don't change value of `m2` as shown below then it shows different id locations of `m2` and `c`.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,dataval=None):
        self.val = dataval ##Int
        self.nextval = None ##Node
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self,headval=None):
        self.headval = headval ##Node

m2 = Node(4)
print(id(m2)) # Returns 2582642884560

c = Node(4)
print(id(c)) # Returns 2582642884320 which is not same as id of m2
```

I was not able to know the reason why in first code, id of `c` is same as previous id of `m2` rather than not assigning it a new memory location.

Comment: what python interpreter are you using? i can't reproduce that behavior...

Comment: I am using Atom.